# Number and size of images in the drawable folder

Tags: android, android-image, android-drawable

I'm writing a program about letters for babies and I'm using 28 images. It's a flashcard program, and was running ok until I reached 20 images.

It force-closes before opening. I'm still in my early stage in the program. I put my images in the drawable-mdpi. After working on this error for 2 days, I discovered that when I split the images between drawable-mdpi and drawable-hdpi it works well, but the images that are in the hdpi folder are smaller, although they are of the same size.

I want to know, why does it work when splitting the images? Is there a limit to the number of images per folder? And also, why do images that are in the hdpi folder get smaller in the app?

Comment: can you show us codes & errors ?

Comment: You might be getting OOM exception because of large bitmap or Bitmap Memory Leaks.
Post your logcat error message.
You can put any number of images in drawable folder.your APK size must be less then 50 MB.

Answer (score 1):

There is no limit of the number of images per folder. I have an application with more than 360 pictures in the folder drawable-mdpi (really) for a total size of 32Mb and it works well.

If you test your application on a mdpi screen (160dpi), and you had hdpi images (for 240dpi), then the application automatically reduces them at run time by multiplying their size by a factor 160/240 = 0.66, which explains why they appear smaller.

See [Multiple screen support for Android](http://developer.android.com/guide/practices/screens_support.html) for more information.

Comment: Actually I had to divide them into mdpi and ldpi, it worked by this, but it's not what I want to get. big photos shrink when they r in the mdpi

Answer (score 0):

The `dpi` are the "Dots Per Inch", Android allows a simple way to ensure that the Device running the application will load the best available resources, for its "bucket", the category of `dpi` it uses.

You can disable this behavior, by creating another drawable folder (such as `res\drawable-nodpi`), and place your bitmaps there, and then loading then, and doing any mutation as needed.